# Cartesian equation of vectors dermine if lines are parallel

Tags: vectors

Determine whether the following planes and lines are parallel. If they are parallel, show whether the line lies in the plane.

(i) $\mathbf r = (3, 1, 2) + t(1, -1,  2)$   and $3x +y - z = 8$

How do you do these type of questions?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

We see immediately that the point of the line $(3,1,2)$ (the point for $t=0$) is on the plane. Now verifies that also the point for $t=1$ is on the plane.

Comment: Haha smart method.

Answer (score 0):

computing the dot product we get $$[3;1;-1]\cdot[1;-1;2]=3-1-2=0$$ this means that the straight line and the plane is parallel